# Call to undefined method stdClass::getVatRemoved()

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

There is observer in my magento 1 site for event `vat_check_after`.

In this observer the code is:

```
$validation_result = $observer->getEvent()->getValidationResult();
if($validation_result->getVatRemoved() == true){
.....
}
```

but in one page checkout there is exception thrown:

> Call to undefined method stdClass::getVatRemoved()

I did not find this method anywhere so what should I do to prevent exception? How can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `$observer->getEvent()->getValidationResult()` return an instance of `stdClass`.
This means, you can get the value you need like this `$validation->result->vat_removed`

Comment: Ok with my vars it would be like: $validation_result->result->vat_removed OR  $validation_result->vat_removed? Please let me know.

Comment: I have no idea how $validator_result looks like. You can check how `$validation_result`. You can do that with a simple `var_dump`.